# Understanding edge coloring for graphs

Tags: graphs, colorings

I'm working on a graph problem that basically boils down to an edge-coloring problem. I have a graph where all vertices have (at most) an in-degree of 2 and an out-degree of 1. I thought this would make it such that I could color all edges using only 3 colors, however based on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring), it seems like this doesn't necessarily have to be true and it's possible I have a "class 2" graph.

I'm trying to understand how that would occur with the simplest example possible. In other words, what's the smallest graph with vertices containing a maximum in-degree of 2 and out-degree of 1 that *cannot* be colored with 3 colors alone?

So far the simplest example I can find is the one below. Note that regardless there's no way to color the graph below with only 3 colors such that each vertex has 3 unique colors.

[image]

Comment: [Tietze's graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze%27s_graph) is one such graph that requires $4$ edge colors. Other such graphs are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_graph#Coloring_and_independent_sets).

Comment: Thanks those are helpful to look at! I was looking for something super simple. I attached a diagram of the simplest graph I could find (which I think might be the simplest overall?). Trying to build up some kind of intuition about this problem.

Comment: You already have a graph with only 5 vertices.  If you want to know whether there is a smaller example, I suggest you code up a program to do exhaustive search over all smaller graphs, and test how many colors it takes to edge-color each such graph.  There aren't that many such graphs.  See also http://oeis.org/A000273, http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html, http://keithbriggs.info/images/g4.pdf,  http://keithbriggs.info/images/g5.pdf, https://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html#nodes2

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll give that a shot.